# What is the best way to statistically analyze a score system and number of steps for users?

Tags: usability, statistics, ranking, steps

I'm trying to analyze two measurements, the number of steps it takes the user to complete a task on a website, and a ranking rubric of 1 - 3 (1 is simple and 3 is considered difficult) for each step of how difficult the task is for them to complete.  At the end we are adding up the number of steps and total difficulty, so there will be two totals.  What would be the best way to have a final number for each task?  I could divide the difficulty ranking by the number of steps but wondered if there's a better way to go about it.

Comment: you question is a little vague, just some thoughts. Surely time would be better metric of difficulty and would provide a better cost to the business, it would also allow you to measure improvement? You should consider researching kablachs book on the subject. https://www.amazon.com/Mapping-Experiences-Complete-Creating-Blueprints-ebook/dp/B01F9Y6B9K

Comment: I'd also go with time if you want to measure something.  The things you are proposing to measure are far too subjective, so any numbers you get will be meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

John Brooke's SUS provides a kind of quantitative evaluation and final number/score that could be customized for doing task analysis. Template can be found here: https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/system-usability-scale.html ...consider leveraging that.

Answer (score 1):

Your metrics probably cannot be easily aggregated into one number. One is subjective (ranking) the other objective (number of steps).

One way to summarize both could be to use a grading system (A+, B, ...) which you devise using a rubric. For instance, you can decide that 3 or less steps and a 1 is considered a A+. Then you could show the distribution for each grade. For instance most people had a B-, whereas the top 15% has A+.

Answer (score 0):

Look at GOMS analysis.
GOMS is a family of predictive models of human performance that can be used to improve the efficiency of human-machine interaction by identifying and eliminating unnecessary user actions. GOMS stands for (Goals, Operators, Methods, and Selection).